# How does the chunksize parameter in pandas.read_sql() avoid loading data into memory

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm iterating through the results of `pd.read_sql(query, engine, chunksize=10000)`

I'm doing this with `engine` (sqlalchemy) set to `echo=True` so that it prints out the raw sql commands that Pandas is hitting the db (postgres) with.

The printouts show that Pandas hits the db only once with exactly the query I wrote, without any modifications. With this in mind, how is it possible for Pandas to iterate through the full output of that query in chunks, while also not storing all chunks in memory at once?

Comment: Please post a more complete example.  One possibility is that it reads the entire dataset into memory in C, then parcels it out to python in smaller chunks.

Comment: I guess it is read into dataframe of chunksize - with fetch - and stored there until something is done with the data - then fetch another chunk etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single SQL query makes the database aware of which results it needs to return.

Actually returning the results is handled by the communication protocol that your driver (probably psycopg2 for python) handles.

[That protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/protocol.html) allows for streaming result sets. Those results can then be chunked at either the driver and/or pandas layer without executing multiple SQL statements.